# missing text displaying outside of the textview

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

i have this layout :[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iJJl.jpg)

as you see at the end of the textview I have missing word displaying outside of the textview it should be displayed in the next line  I didn't found a way to solve this problme.n the case of (utilisateurs) it is displaying fine by the way .

Here is my xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout

xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="12dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickStatus"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickDate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickPriority"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickImpact"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickUrgency"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/clickcontent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/round_edittext"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/traitement"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Traitement " />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>

<com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_margin="24dp"
    app:fab_addButtonColorNormal="@color/yellow"
    app:fab_labelStyle="@style/floting_button">

    <com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_supprimer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:fab_colorNormal="@color/dark_blue"
        app:fab_icon="@drawable/ic_supprimer"
        app:fab_title="Supprimer ticket" />

</com.getbase.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionsMenu>
```

appreciate any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use padding within the `TextView` to solve the problem.